# Map from video game with Cartesian coordinates in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: web-mapping, mapbox-gl-js, cartesian

I want to create an interactive map in the browser from the RPG video game. I think I'm quite experienced in both backend and frontend development, so this is definitely **not** one of that naive questions, but I'm pretty new in the word of GIS.

**Background**

The game map uses Cartesian coordinates `x,y,z` and has approximately 4 km². The base internal unit is 1 cm. `z = 0` is sea level and all three coordinates go into negative values too.

I exported the whole map into the Blender and already recreate a small part of the map in the [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) format. I'm using multiple [FeatureCollections](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.3) to describe lands, rivers, buildings, etc. I kept coordinates for the polygons the same as they are in the game. I'm using just `x` and `y` coordinates.

And now, I want to use some library to visualize it on the web. I did quite a big research and find these two (free) mainstream libraries - [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) and [Mapbox GL JS](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/). Both can handle GeoJSON as an input, but Mapbox GL JS uses WebGL for the rendering and overall looks a bit *more modern*.

**Question**

I don't know how to project my Cartesian coordinates from the GeoJSON files into Mapbox GL JS lib, so the game's map will not be distorted and when the user clicks somewhere, he gets right coordinates.

**Research**

I created PoC in the Leaflet, where everything seems to work with CRS set to [Simple](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html). But according to [this comment](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3184#issuecomment-558346214) on the Github, Mapbox JS GL doesn't support Cartesian coordinates yet. Can I overcome this limitation somehow? I thought about some projection from `x,y` to `lon,lat` or something, but this is really not my cup of tea...

Comment: You can maybe use web mercator 3857 projection with the Mapbox GL `MercatorCoordinate` and set your origin to Null Island (0.5, 0.5, 0). Your map of 4 km² have a delta in X and Y of `0,0001` units (4 / 40075 km).